# How to know previous step execution STATUS in next step in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, batch-processing

I have a batch job with 3 steps.I want to read the `STATUS (COMPLETED/FAILED)` of `step 2` in my `Step 3` to take a business decision.

I don't want to use `next on="COMPLETED" to="Tasklet1" next on="FAILED" to="Tasklet2"` in the batch configuration of `Step 2`; because i need to write two tasklets.

I want to achieve this using only one Tasklet. Is there a way i can know the step execution STATUS of Step 2 in my Step 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you got the solutions by now. In case not;

I do not know why you want to check for FAILED status as the job will terminate if the step is failed. It will not reach to the next step.

Still for the previous step status, you can check with jobExecution.

```
List<JobExecution> jobExecutions = jobExplorer.getJobExecutions(jobInstance);
for (JobExecution jobExecution : jobExecutions) {
   // Make sure the execution id is the current id
   // Then get the list of stepExecutions from jobExecution
   jobExecution.getStemExecutions();
   // From the list, check for the step you are looking for and then
   stepExecution.getExitStatus();
}
```

The code is not the complete code and compilable, however iwll give you an idea about what you are looking for.